# openSUSE RVM/Yast2 Collision?

Tags: ruby, rvm, opensuse

After the last Tumbleweed update (which included a Ruby update I think) I've lost Yast2:

```
eric@linux-epth:~$ su -c '/sbin/yast2 sw_single'
Password: 
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- yast (LoadError)
from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /usr/lib/YaST2/bin/y2start:9:in `<main>'
```

Thought I'd traced it to a conflict with rvm but removing rvm from the PATH did not help with the problem (did not remove ~/.rvm though):

```
eric@linux-epth:~$ env | grep RUBY
eric@linux-epth:~$ su -c '/sbin/yast2 sw_single'
Password: 
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- yast (LoadError)
from /usr/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /usr/lib/YaST2/bin/y2start:9:in `<main>'
```

eric@linux-epth:~$

Any ideas on how to reinstate Yast2? Is this a clash with RVM?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with iso repo that should have been delete. Solved.